# How to reference a public int within a class with a string

Tags: java, oop, file, variables, public

I'm working on a text-based adventure game and I'm trying to externalise as much of the setup as possible so that I can work with a friend who wants to write the storyline. I have three classes so far. A room class with a title, description, and an array of Exits. Also an Exit class with the following constructor.

```
public Exit(int direction, Room connection);
```

Exits also have public int variables referring to the different directions:

```
public static final int NORTH = 0;
```

This is all so I can set up an exit on a room by saying:

```
Room r = new Room("Title","Description");
Room r2 = new Room("Title", "Description");

r.addExit(new Exit(Exit.NORTH, r2);
```

This would make an exit on the room r that is on the north side and leads to the room r2. Now for the externalisation I'm trying to make a .txt file where I can simply put the current room number, the exit direction (string), and the room number it leads to.

I can do this just fine as far as reading the file goes but where I'm struggling is when I'm setting up the direction, I can't say

```
Exit. /*String read from file*/
```

So how can I access those public integers from the Exit class using a string from the txt file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick and dirty fix is to implement a method to do string comparison and return the appropriate constant.  But you should also consider using an `enum` as suggested by BRPocock, it's a much cleaner way to do it.

```
int directionFromStr(String str) {
    // Putting the string constant on the left side of the expression guards against null input
    if ("NORTH".equalsIgnoreCase(str)) return Exit.NORTH;
    if ("SOUTH".equalsIgnoreCase(str)) return Exit.SOUTH;
    if ("EAST".equalsIgnoreCase(str)) return Exit.EAST;
    if ("WEST".equalsIgnoreCase(str)) return Exit.WEST;

    // You could also return -1 or something like that
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("bad direction");
}
```

Comment: Yeah I was hoping there was an easier way than this. Didn't really want to make more helper methods. I'll look into enum, thanks for lettuce answer though.

Comment: Big vote up though because I didn't know that about putting the string constant on the left side guarding against null!

Answer (score 2):

Try using an `enum` instead.

```
  public enum ExitDirection { NORTH = 0, … };

  ExitDirection foo = ExitDirection.valueOf (stringFromFile);
```

…else, you'll just have to bite the bullet with something like

`if (stringFromFile.equals("NORTH")) { foo = NORTH; }
 else if (stringFromFile` ... *(ad nauseum)*

Comment: Interesting. I haven't learned enums yet. I'll look into that.

Comment: So is this done within the Exit class? And if so would I reference it by saying:

    Exit.ExitDirection.valueOf(stringFromFile);

Comment: If you're not using them anywhere else, putting them in as an interior class isn't a bad idea. If they're more generally useful, you might break them out to a “top-level” class of their own. (An `enum` is a special-case class … but not terribly special. It just gets some syntactic sugar added.)